# Visual Studio 2015 Failing to Connect to Team Foundation Server 2017: TF31002

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, tfs

We have setup a trial version of TFS 2017 in order to see if we would like to purchase a full version for our development shop.  Only one developer can connect to TFS 2017 with Visual Studio and at no point was he involved with the initial setup of TFS.

I am running Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise and I have tried the following items with no fruition on fixing the attached image.

1. Check that I can connect through a browser to TFS from my box.  Works.
2. Check to see if I can telnet to the server on port 8080.  Works.
3. White list Visual Studio and port 8080 in my firewall.  Done.
4. Reinstall Visual Studio from scratch.  Done.
5. Try to log into TFS from a different box using same credentials.  Done and Works.
6. Clear cache for Visual Studio and TFS.  Done.
7. Try running Visual Studio as Admin.  Done.

I have tried all of the above (and quite a few other things) and at no point can I connect to TFS through Visual Studio.  As it stands now I don't see my shop going down the road of using TFS.

If anyone has an idea for what to do, I'm all ears I would really like our shop to migrate to TFS based on what I have heard about it.

[image: Error Message from Visual Studio 2015]

Comment: Which VS2015 version do you use? Do you have Update 3 installed?

Comment: Update 3 is installed. Full Version is 14.0.25431.01 Update 3.

Comment: I'm not sure about that, but it's possible, that only one developer is allowed to connect to the trial version of TFS2017. Try to start VS with the [/Log parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241272.aspx) and check the created log file under C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ActivityLog.xml.
Another thing you could check: Setup a free account on Azure and try to connect to the VSTS.

Comment: Do you have proxy configured in the network environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*TF31002* is a very wide range of error messages, you might receive this error when you try to  from Visual Studio or Team Explorer connect to VSTS or an on-premises Team Foundation Server (TFS).

Since the problem occurs on more than one computer, you could ask administrator, the **event logs** for the application-tier server to try to pinpoint the problem.

I will suggest you to disable your firewall first, White list sometimes not so thoroughly and try the connection again. If it's still not work, give a try with  **accessing your TFS with IP address** (e.g. `http://[ip]:8080/tfs`) which may did the trick.

Also, you can use the table in [Several users receive this error when they try to connect to an on-premises TFS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244143.aspx) to determine whether the server is misconfigured.

Answer (score 0):

I too suffered with this myself. This is a Bug and has been patched by Visual Studio Team. Installing the patch helped me fix this error.
patch : VS14-KB3165756.exe
Download Patch here: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=816878